# run into a odd mode in oh my zsh

Tags: macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh

trying to configuring the oh my zsh, but somehow went into this mode that is not the normal theme looks like and change themes do not work at all and now I cannot even uninstall the oh my zsh.

[image]

This `MacBook-Air%` is the problem.

Comment: This looks like your `~/.zshrc` does either no longer set a theme or dose no longer load *Oh-My-Zsh* or may be gone entirely. Provided *Oh-My-Zsh* is still there, you should find a template for `~/.zshrc` at `~/.oh-my-zsh/templates/zshrc.zsh-template`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me.I cannot get in the file, it says permission denied

Comment: In that case you may somehow have changed the permissions or ownership of the file(a). Which would also explain why you cannot uninstall oh-my-zsh. You can try running `chown -R USER:GROUP ~/.zshrc ~/.oh-my-zsh`, replacing `USER` and `GROUP` with the actual values for your account of course.

Comment: What should I put for `GROUP`?